# App crashing on opening a new activity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm new to Android programming but want to make an app that will store users' data on Firebase and bring it back. I got the Authentication to work but as soon as I redirect it to to the form where they have to fill in the details but it crashes whenever I try to login.

```
package example.com.myapplication;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;




public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



private Button Signup, Signin, FPbtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    Signin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Loginbtn);
    Signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signupbtn);
    FPbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.FPBtn);

    //Forgot Password

    FPbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ResetPassword.class));
        }
    });

    /* //Register Method

    Signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernamefield);
        EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordfield);
        String email3 = email.getText().toString();
        final String password3 = password.getText().toString();

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email3)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password3)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else
                {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, OTP.class));
            }


        }
    }); */

    Signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, sign_up.class));
        }
    });


    //Login Method

    Signin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()


    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernamefield);
            EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordfield);
            String email2 = email.getText().toString();
            final String password2 = password.getText().toString();


            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email2)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password2)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email2, password2)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getString(R.string.auth_failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } else {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Profile.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            }
                        }
                    });

        }

    });
    }
}
```

And then this is the Profile.Java file that I want to redirect it to

```
package example.com.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;




public class Profile extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText t1,t2,t3,t4,t5;
private Button b1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            t1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.FirstNameField);
            t2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.LastNameField);
            t3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.AgeField);
            t4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.WL1);
            t5 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.WL2);
            b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ProfSubmit);

            FirebaseDatabase User1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            DatabaseReference Name = User1.getReference("Fname");
            DatabaseReference LName = User1.getReference("LName");
            DatabaseReference age = User1.getReference("age");
            DatabaseReference Work1 = User1.getReference("WorkLink1");
            DatabaseReference Work2 = User1.getReference("WorkLink2");

            Name.setValue(t1.getText());
            LName.setValue(t2.getText());
            age.setValue(t3.getText());
            Work1.setValue(t4.getText());
            Work2.setValue(t5.getText());

            startActivity(new Intent(Profile.this, HomeScreen.class));
            finish();
        }
    });



// ...
    }
}
```

Comment: The database has the login details right. I tried linking other activities in the intent and it works. I am not getting any errors of java compile errors either. (Don't mind the commentified block of code in the MainActivity. It's something that didn't work but I was lazy about removing it)

Comment: Can you post the log also

Comment: Instead of starting new activity by MainActivity.this context, make a global variable of context, initialize it in onCreate() method Or else make onClick function for that button and put the same code that starts the new Activity...I have faced the same problem and it resolve by this method

Comment: @SidharthAnil I tried using my Phone in debug mode to get a log but I ended up with this instead. I've been building APKs and installing them on my phone manually till now. 

http://dumptext.com/vpKDN5kR

Comment: @JayPatel Can you elaborate please?

Comment: What new activity is stopping the program. Since you have multiple

Comment: @Tacolibre The profile activity is stopping the program. It basically crashes when sent to it. It works fine for other screens and works fine with only the generated code. It is when I want to add the Firebase functionality does it crash.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code with first file and add onClick methods for respective buttons as defined in this code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button Signup, Signin, FPbtn;    
EditText email,password;
final FirebaseAuth mAuth;    
Context cntx;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernamefield);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordfield);

    Signin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Loginbtn);
    Signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signupbtn);
    FPbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.FPBtn);                        
    cntx = this;
}        

//Declare this method as onClick method for Fpbtn 
public void FpbtnClickMethod(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent(cntx, ResetPassword.class));
}

//Declare this method as onClick method for SignUp button
public void SignupOnClickMethod(View view){
    startActivity(new Intent(cntx, sign_up.class));
}        

//Declare this method as onClick method for Sign In button
public void SignInOnClickMethod(View view){
    String email2 = email.getText().toString();
    final String password2 = password.getText().toString();


    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email2)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password2)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email2, password2)
            .addOnCompleteListener(cntx, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(cntx, getString(R.string.auth_failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(cntx, Profile.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            });
}
}
```

Here, the cntx variable will resolve the context problem that occured in anonymous inner class of onClick